# Can't get JS script to work when redirecting to different page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am trying to make a script to make accounts on a game I play called Evony.

On the page to make an account, I found the element IDs for the email and password textboxes and tried to input the text into them, but my code is not working for some reason.

The link to the create account page is located here: http://user.evony.com/index.do?PageModule=ForgetPassword

Here's what I've tried:

```
<?php

?>
<html>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL=http://user.evony.com/index.do?PageModule=ForgetPassword">//loads webpage
    <script>
        var email = email;
        var password = password;
        var accnumber = 0;
        function createaccount(){   
            // Click the button to bring up create acc tab
            document.getElementById("tab2").click()

            // If the clicking above doesn't work,
            // this should manually bring up the tab 
            // to create the acc
            document.getElementById('tab_login_c').style.display='none';

            // Part of above
            document.getElementById('tab_reg_c').style.display='';
            this.className='on'" class="on">

            // This is to input the email into the email box
            document.getElementById('username').value = email + accnumber + "@yahoo.com";
        }

        // Execute the code
        window.onload = function () { createaccount() }
    </script>
</html>
```

My code isn't fully finished yet as far as entering the password, and I don't have a loop to increase `x` -- I'm trying to get this part to work first.

To run this, I am using XAMPP and going into Chrome and `127.0.0.1:5555`.

It loads the webpage, but doesn't run any of the JavaScript. Any help would be great!

Comment: PSS: Elements from the page:
Button to switch to register acc tab:
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="tab2" onclick="
    document.getElementById('tab_login_c').style.display='none';
    document.getElementById('tab_reg_c').style.display='';
    this.className='on'" class="on"><span></span></a>
Elements for email:
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" class="input2">

Comment: Why are you redirecting the user before the Javascript is run? If you think that it *loads the page* then you are mistaken. Also, where do you get the variables `email` and `password`?

Comment: Doesnt the user has to be on the website before the js can run? Or else how would the js put the email and password in the boxes? what do you mean it doesnt load the page? I can see the page and interact withit and make accs manually? Also tried to comment out that line and it still doesnt work - thanks for the suggestion though.

Comment: Ahhh, you think you are loading the website into your page and then running your Javascript on that page? That is not what is happening. What the `<meta...>` tag is doing is redirecting the user to another page, leaving your page behind. This means that the Javascript on your page is never run, because the user is redirected before it can run. Even if it ran it would not do anything.

Comment: I want it to run on the page that it gets redircted too - since the code comes after the re-dircection shouldnt it still run?

Comment: @mrbad315 No, it will not run. Once the `<meta...>` tag is read by the browser everything stops and the user is immediately redirected to that link. Your page is closed and no longer active.

Comment: oh wow (facepalm) well thanks for the answers lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, your approach is fundamentally impossible.

When you instruct your HTML to redirect and load the user account page, your web browser will move completely away from the webpage you've written, losing all of the JavaScript code you've written. There's really no clean way to have one page load another webpage and try and inject JavaScript into it.

In fact, pretty much every single web browser in existence will actually try and actively *stop* one webpage from pretending to be another webpage, and injecting arbitrary JavaScript. This is because doing so can lead to all sorts of security vulnerabilities -- see [cross-site scripting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_scripting) if you're interested in learning more.

In order to get this to work, you need to do one of the following:

1. Directly send requests to Evony's servers instead of filling out their text boxes
2. Use something like [Greasemonkey](http://www.greasespot.net/) to write a user script that'll run your JavaScript code.
3. Write your script using a web automation tool like [Selenium](http://www.seleniumhq.org/) or a more general automation tool like [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

I would also take a close look at Evony's terms of service -- I doubt that they sanction automatically creating a large amount of accounts, and you will most likely get into trouble if you use these accounts in order to abuse or exploit the game.

Comment: How do I go about Sending the request directly to evony's server?

Comment: @mrbad315 Put a link to their website on your page. If you want to do it dynamically (such as when a button is clicked) then you can do so like this: `window.location = "http://...";`.

Comment: Would you mind going a little into detail a little bit more?
(sorry if im asking alot - im pretty new to js and coding in general really)

Comment: @mrbad315 -- here is some [more information](http://eloquentjavascript.net/17_http.html) on the fundamentals of interacting with servers using JavaScript. I doubt that just setting `window.location` will actually do anything -- if you want to automatically sign yourself up, you basically write code that'll send your data over using exactly the same format that Evony does on their webpage. This can be a bit tricky -- I honestly think it'll be easier to just switch to using something like Greasemonkey and port your JS code over, or learn a new language and use one of the options I presented.

Comment: Thanks and is greasemonkey only in firefox?

Comment: and also is there a way to find out the format that i must send it in?

Comment: @mrbad315 -- Yes, greasemonkey is Firefox-only. However, if you google "greasemonkey chrome", you can find some alternative plugins that will do basically the same thing as Greasemonkey, except for Chrome.

Comment: @mrbad315 -- you can discover the format by using your browser's web console to examine the requests the signup page is sending to the server, looking at the data they send over, and examining how it's formatted. Again, it's much easier to just use something like Greasemonkey, Selenium, or AutoHotKey and write code that'll fill in the text boxes and click the submit button.

Comment: Ok once again thank you very much and for my last question do you know any tuts that will explain how grease-monkey works like as far as whats the difference between using grease-monkey and just making a php/js file?

Comment: @mrbad315 -- not off the top of my head. Try googling "greasemonkey tutorial" and see what comes up.